# Plugin for Task Management in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there any plugin for task management ( bug tracking, issues) to use with xcode? Or there's any plugin api that one can create plugins for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There really isnt anything that I know of that is as good as mylyn to intergrate with bugzilla or trac. If you found anything, please let me know!

The best way I know of to document issues or things is to put a //TODO: or //FIXME: in your code. Then when Xcode compiles you can run a local shell script to post warnings for you

Its here: (Targets -->  --> BUILD PHASES --> Run Scripts  (See Screenshot)

Put this script at the end of your Build Phases  :

```
KEYWORDS="FIXME|TODO:|FIXME:|\?\?\?:|\!\!\!:"
find ${SRCROOT} \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -print0 | \
xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | \
perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/ warning: \$1/"
```

Lastly there is the infamous

`#pragma mark YOURTEXTHERE`

Good Luck!

Here is a wishlist of things people want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025605/wishlist-for-objective-c-ide-xcode

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: There is also one for Auto Incrementing Build Numbers, run another script afterward to increment your build number in the *-Info.plist

Comment: I meant the Auto-Incrementing build number :)

Comment: I cant fit the script here. Please follow this link to a [blog post](http://kickinespresso.com/post/15278203227/auto-incrementing-build-number-script-for-xcode-4)

Comment: First off, great solution!  I have spaces embedded in my project's path.  The spaces are hosing up the script you posted.  I'm not strong in shell scripting.  Is there a way to make your script handle spaces embedded in the path?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using the Run Script build phase for a while now and modified it so the generated build warnings directly link to the file and line where the keyword has been found.

The solution is just to print a line which matches the ones Xcode knows how to parse:

```
{filename}:{line}:{character}: warning: {The content of the warning}.
```

So the script looks like that:

```
KEYWORDS="FIXME|TODO:|FIXME:|\?\?\?:|\!\!\!:\@todo\@warning"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -exec egrep -Hno "($KEYWORDS).*\$" {} \; | \
sed -e 's/^\([^:]\{1,\}\):\([0-9]\{1,\}\):\(.*\)$/\1:\2:1: warning: \3/'
```

Note that I also included @todo and @warning in the keywords as I often use javadoc/doxygen comments.

Bertrand

Answer (score 0):

I made a Xcode plugin for this  --> http://github.com/trawor/XToDo