# Xcode Bug Tracking

Tags: xcode, redmine

We have a server setup with Redmine to track our bugs. It seems that Eclipse has an option to integrate with Redmine but I don't see anything for Xcode.

Are there any options for something like this?

Comment: This would be an interesting question to answer (so +1 to you), but I suspect nothing is available at this date [while XCode 4 offers no plugin support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316921/xcode-4-plugin-development).

Comment: That's a shame. That would make things much, much easier.

Comment: File a feature request with Apple at bugreport.apple.com. If/when enough people ask for the same feature, sometimes it can become reality.

Comment: You got it! I'll do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a way. After further Google-ing and the clarification from Michael Dautermann, I have confirmed this.

Answer (score 2):

There are no thirdparty plugins for Xcode. The API for Xcode is undocumented and not supported even though things like [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/) and [codepilot](http://codepilot.cc/) exist.

This is something I've been looking for also. Here are a few alternate solutions, but you'll have to change something....

Bug Tracking: [LightHouse](http://lighthouseapp.com/)

App for lighthouse: [lighthouse app](http://www.mcubedsw.com/software/lighthousekeeper)

IDE: [AppCode by JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) (AppCode Supports thirdparty plugins, but you will have to do your own research to determine if redmine is supported. They do have their own bug tracker called YouTrack or something)

Also, Check out my other post on [using a script to do some internal bug tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6867978/703161)